# Unable to append data into my file using fwrite in PHP

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body> 
<?php
    $v=fopen("exc.csv", "a")or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($v,"appended txt\r\n");
    fclose($v);
?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

it is working perfectly but whenever I try to run this code while exc.csv file is open in my computer, I'm getting this error:

> Warning: fopen(exc.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied.

I've already tried using chmod() and setting the permission to 0777 and its still not working. Is there any way that I can write into a file while it is physically open? If not, please tell me why.

Comment: Modifying a file that is in use is prevented by some operating systems. Which OS do you use?

Comment: You sure that exc.csv is not opened in another editor somewhere at the same time?

Comment: yes @SergeyVidusov and that's the problem. is there a way to write on that file using php while it's already open in windows excel?

Comment: Yes. Close the Excel :) No other way.

Comment: You should try using `file_put_contents`

    file_put_contents("exc.csv","appended text", FILE_APPEND);

Comment: Maybe it works if there is some option to open the file as read only in excel?

Comment: @TobyAllen, I've already tried file_put_contents but it doesn't work

Comment: There will be multiple excel files and I cannot make the users set some option on those files @maxhb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware of it is not possible - or at least not on Windows. The thing is the file is already locked by another process. As soon as you open a file for editing in an editor, it is read only for all other processes. The reason is to prevent collision of two processes modifying the same file.

Comment: Yes, just like in php if you open a file you pass a flag for read or write or both. If in write then it is locked so that nothing else can write at the same time

Comment: It makes sense. I guess I'll just prompt the user to close the file first before appending data or something. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @Vance, you are welcome. Please, mark the answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: This strongly depends on the application. Just opened a file with OpenOffice Writer and php can still write to that file. Same is true for UltraEdit text editor.

Comment: yeah, Notepad++ does not block a file either, but Excel obviously opens the read/write file handle and keeps it for itself.

Comment: Wow that's very nice to know. I think I'll just stick to the idea that PHP can't hookup with a file that's already taken by an app